# $.ajax() call returns data but $.post() returns "undefined"

Tags: jquery, ajax

Could someone help me figure out why when I call a web service with $.ajax() call it returns expected data, and when I call the same service with $.post() call, returned data is "undefined"?

Please note that while inspecting Response with google's tool (for the .post() call) I can see the data sent back from server but somehow it is unavailable to the .done() function of the .post() call.

Program completes without errors.

Here is the whole code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Test01</title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#btn01").click(function () {
                //.ajax type call
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "WebService1.asmx/GetData",
                    data: "{KenID:'11'}",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data)
                    {
                        $("#div01").html(data.d);
                    }
                });
            });
            $("#btn02").click(function () {
                // .post() type call
                $.post("WebService1.asmx/GetData", { KenID: "11" })
                    .done(function (data, status)
                    {
                        $("#div01").html("Data: " + data.d + "</br>Status: " + status);
                    })
                    .fail(function () { alert("error"); })
                    .always(function () { alert("completed"); });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="div01">Here comes the result</div>
    <button id="btn01">Load Data with $.ajax : </button>
    <button id="btn02">Load Data with $.post : </button>
    <input id="KenID" value="11" />
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you,

Jacek

Answer (score 3):

You need to define response is `json` in `$.post`.

**Example**

```
$.post(
    "WebService1.asmx/GetData",
    { KenID: "11" },
    function(response)
    {
        //code
    }, 'json' // <-- HERE
);
```

Comment: Thank you Dipesh. New code gives error                    $.post("WebService1.asmx/GetData", { KenID: "11" },
                          function(response)
                            {
                                $("#div01").html("Data: " + data.d + "</br>Status: " + status);
                            }, 'json' // <-- HERE
                    )
                    ....

Comment: The success function is still receiving "undefined" response, whether dataType 'json' is specified or not ...  No errors reported, google's Response shows data coming from server

Comment: $.ajax is working fine, $.post always returns undefined, even though server sends the data

Comment: I think there is something wrong with data handling in "success" function because if I define dataType as "html" the response is "undefined", while for "json" datType the .fail function is invoked giving "error"

Comment: @user2223670 make sure `WebService1.asmx/GetData` give json as response....check in firebug

Comment: actually its annoying firebug shows response data and same data is coming as undefined for me in js

Answer (score 0):

it is basically $.post is return the xml base data type. If you see in firebug in Console log and in Response tab you will find the response type. some thing like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">test</string>
```

So I recommend you to cast the XML response into string data type. For this please see: 
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/.

Hope it will help you.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please refer  below code snippet.

```
$.post(""WebService1.asmx/GetData",", {id : $("#hID").val()}, function(data)
{
  doSomething( data.toString() );
});

function doSomething( data)
{
  // whatever
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse your JSON request using **urlencoded** before lauching your server.

Beware to launch your http server **AFTER** using the urlencoder not before.

Eg.

```
app.use(express.urlencoded());

http.createServer(app).listen(3000)
```

without :
$ node server.js

> undefined

with :
$ node server.js

> { description: ''}
>
> data has been posted to the server!